# Trying to extend the bottom of an image in react native

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error in my code, style does not exist?

image={require, style={ height: 30 }('../images/49.jpeg')}>

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong formula

It should be like that

```
<Image style={{height: 30}} source={require('/images/49.jpeg')} />
```

Answer (score -1):

put the style in a view surrounding the image

```
<View style={{height: 30}}>
  <Image source={require('/images/49.jpeg')} />
</View>
```